# Calculation of simplex coordinates that are bound by vectors and the simplex has to contain a target coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, simplex, barycentric-coordinates

Notation:

- $p_{i, j, k}$; the $k^{th}$ component of the $j^{th}$ boundary coordinate on the $i^{th}$ boundary

## Finding a weight in 2D

I have **2** sets of 2 boundary coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$ space.
The boundaries and their coordinates are indicated in **green** in Figure 1 below.
Corresponding coordinates in each set are tied together by a line (a tie-line or tie-1-simplex).
The tie-1-simplices are indicated in **solid red** in Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1: Two sets of 2 boundary coordinates in <span class=]$\mathbb{R}^2$" />

In each set ($i$), I can create a vector; $\bar{v}_i = p_{i, 2} - p_{i, 1} \quad :i \in \mathbb{N} [1, 2]$

A point on a vector can be described by the two coordinates and a weight; $r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, \beta) = p_{i,1} + \beta \bar{v}_i = p_{i,1}+ \beta(p_{i,2} - p_{i,1}) \quad :\beta \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

Within the convex hull of these coordinates I have another target coordinate; $p_t$, indicated in **blue** in Figure 1.

A simplex of $\mathbb{R}^1$ (a line), indicated in **hashed red** in Figure 1, exist in this $\mathbb{R}^2$ space that contains the target coordinate and whose vertices are found on each of the vectors where the weight $\beta$ is the same for both vectors.

Given the sets of boundary coordinates and target coordinate, how can I explicitly calculate $\beta$. An iterative method is to be avoided as this calculation is critical to the performance of an algorithm.

## Finding a weight in 3D. Case 1

This is very similar to the 2D case.

I have **3** sets of 2 boundary coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space.
The boundaries and their coordinates are indicated in **green** in Figure 2 below.
Corresponding coordinates in each set are tied together by a triangle (a tie-triangle or tie-2-simplex).
The tie-2-simplices are indicated in **solid red** in Figure 2.

[image: Figure 2: Three sets of 2 boundary coordinates in <span class=]$\mathbb{R}^3$" />

In each set ($i$), I can create a vector; $\bar{v}_i = p_{i, 2} - p_{i, 1} \quad :i \in \mathbb{N} [1, 3]$

A point on a vector can be described by the two coordinates and a weight; $r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, \beta) = p_{i,1} + \beta \bar{v}_i = p_{i,1}+ \beta(p_{i,2} - p_{i,1}) \quad :\beta \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

Within the convex hull of these coordinates I have another target coordinate; $p_t$, indicated in **blue** in Figure 2.

A simplex of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (a triangle), indicated in **hashed red** in Figure 2, exist in this $\mathbb{R}^3$ space that contains the target coordinate and whose vertices are found on each of the vectors where the weight $\beta$ is the same for both vectors.

Given the sets of boundary coordinates and target coordinate, how can I explicitly calculate $\beta$. An iterative method is to be avoided as this calculation is critical to the performance of an algorithm.

## Finding a weight in 3D. Case 2

Similar to the first 3D case where the boundaries were lines (one vector per boundary), in this case the boundaries are surfaces defined by three coordinates (two vectors per boundary).

I now have **2** sets of 3 boundary coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space.
The boundaries and their coordinates are indicated in **green** in Figure 3 below.
Corresponding coordinates in each set are tied together by a line (a tie-line or tie-1-simplex).
The tie-1-simplices are indicated in **solid red** in Figure 3.

[image: Figure 3: Two sets of 3 boundary coordinates in <span class=]$\mathbb{R}^3$" />

In each set ($i$), I can create two vectors, each originating from the same coordinate (coordinate 1 for instance); $\bar{v}_{i, 12}  = p_{i, 2} - p_{i, 1}, \bar{v}_{i, 13}  = p_{i, 3} - p_{i, 1} \quad :i \in \mathbb{N} [1, 2]$

With these two vectors, I can describe a coordinate on the surface created between them.
A point on the surface can be described by the three coordinates and two weights; $r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, p_{i, 3}, \beta_1, \beta_2) = p_{i,1} + \beta_1 \bar{v}_{i, 12} + \beta_2 \bar{v}_{i, 13} = p_{i,1}+ \beta_1(p_{i,2} - p_{i,1}) + \beta_2(p_{i,3} - p_{i,1}) \quad :\beta_i \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]; \beta_i >= 0; \Sigma{\beta_i} <= 1$

Within the convex hull of these coordinates I have another target coordinate; $p_t$, , indicated in **blue** in Figure 3.

A simplex of $\mathbb{R}^1$ (a line), indicated in **hashed red** in Figure 3, exist in this $\mathbb{R}^3$ space that contains the target coordinate and whose vertices are found on each of the surfaces described by the two sets of vectors where the weights $\beta_i$ and $\beta_2$ are the same for each surface.

Given the sets of boundary coordinates and target coordinate, how can I explicitly calculate $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. An iterative method is to be avoided as this calculation is critical to the performance of an algorithm.

## Finding a weight in generic case

I would ultimately like to get to the point where I can calculate any number of $\beta$ weights in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there someone that has solved a similar problem before or has a suggestion on how this can be attempted? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an expression that can be used to determine the $\beta$ values, but unfortunately it is not an explicit solution but can be solved with non-linear methods. I have shown below how I derived the solution for each case, referring to some expressions in the question. This was done to show where I got the pattern shown in the generic solution.

Notation:

- $B$; the number of boundaries
- $C$; the number of boundary coordinates a boundary is composed of
- $N$; the dimension where the coordinates are found in
- $p_{i, j, k}$; the $k^{th}$ component of the $j^{th}$ boundary coordinate on the $i^{th}$ boundary

## Finding a weight in 2D

As indicated, a point on each boundary can be represented by the vector that connects the boundary coordinates and a weight, $\beta$;

$r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, \beta) = p_{i,1} + \beta \bar{v}_i = p_{i,1}+ \beta(p_{i,2} - p_{i,1}) \quad :\beta \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

This was expanded and factorised so that each boundary coordinate was expressed individually together with a weight;

$r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, \beta) = p_{i,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{i,2}(\beta) \quad :\beta \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

With the $\beta$ value equal for both boundaries, the two coordinates required to create the tie-simplex that contains the target coordinate, are known, albeit in terms of an unknown variable.
These two coordinates can be used to create another vector, $\bar{t}$, that represents the tie-simplex;

$\bar{s} = r_{2} - r_{1}$

This vector $\bar{s}$, together with a tie-simplex weight, $\alpha$, can be used to express the target coordinate;

$t(r_{1}, r_{2}, \alpha) = r_{1} + \alpha \bar{s} = r_{1} + \alpha(r_{2} - r_{1}) \quad :\alpha \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$.

This was expanded and factorised so that each of the coordinates could be expressed individually together with a weight;

$t(r_{1}, r_{2}, \alpha) = r_{1}(1 - \alpha) + r_{2}(\alpha) \quad :\alpha \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$.

After substituting the expressions for $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$, the target coordinate $t$, can be expressed in terms of the known boundary coordinates, the boundary weight $\beta$, and tie-simplex weight $\alpha$;

$t = r_{1}(1 - \alpha) + r_{2}(\alpha) = [p_{1,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{1,2}(\beta)](1 - \alpha) + [p_{2,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{2,2}(\beta)](\alpha) \quad :\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

After some expanding and factorising, this can be written in matrix and vector notation as;

$\bar{t} = \bf{P}\bar{\omega}$

where

$\bar{t} = \begin{bmatrix}
 t_{x}\\
    t_{y} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\bf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
 p_{1, 1, x} & p_{1, 1, y} \\
    p_{1, 2, x} & p_{1, 2, y} \\
    p_{2, 1, x} & p_{2, 1, y} \\
    p_{2, 2, x} & p_{2, 2, y} \\
\end{bmatrix} ^T$

$\bar{\omega} = \begin{bmatrix}
 (1 - \beta)(1 - \alpha) \\
    (\beta)(1 - \alpha)\\
    (1 - \beta)(\alpha) \\
    (\beta)(\alpha)\\
\end{bmatrix} $

With the target coordinate known as well as all the boundary coordinates, this system of equations can be solved to obtain the boundary weight $\beta$.
This however cannot be done with linear algebra seeing that this is a non-linear expression.

## Finding a weight in 3D, case 1

As with the 2D case, a coordinate can be expressed with the following expression because there are only two coordinates that creates the 1D boundary;

$r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, \beta) = p_{i,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{i,2}(\beta) \quad :\beta 
\in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

In this case however, there are three boundaries, and therefore three coordinates that creates the tie-simplex that contains the target coordinate.
Two vectors can be created from one of the coordinates to the others;

$\bar{s}_1 = r_{2} - r_{1}$, and $\bar{s}_2 = r_{3} - r_{1}$

These vectors $\bar{s}_1$ and $\bar{s}_2$, together with two tie-simplex weights, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, can be used to express the target coordinate;

$t(r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}, \alpha_1, \alpha_2) = r_{1} + \alpha_1 \bar{s}_1 + \alpha_2 \bar{s}_2 = r_{1} + \alpha_1(r_{2} - r_{1}) + \alpha_2(r_{3} - r_{1}) \quad :\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$.

This was expanded and factorised so that each of the coordinates could be expressed individually together with a weight;

$t(r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}, \alpha_1, \alpha_2) = r_{1}(1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2) + r_{2}(\alpha_1) + r_{3}(\alpha_2) \quad :\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$.

After substituting the expressions for $r_{1}$, $r_{2}$ and $r_{2}$, the target coordinate $t$, can be expressed in terms of the known boundary coordinates, the boundary weight $\beta$, and tie-simplex weights $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$;

\begin{align}
t &= r_{1}(1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2) + r_{2}(\alpha_1) + r_{3}(\alpha_2) \\
&= [p_{1,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{1,2}(\beta)](1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2) + [p_{2,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{2,2}(\beta)](\alpha_1) + [p_{3,1}(1 - \beta) + p_{3,2}(\beta)](\alpha_2) \\
& \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]
\end{align}

After some expanding and factorising, this can be written in matrix and vector notation as;

$\bar{t} = \bf{P}\bar{\omega}$

where

$\bar{t} = \begin{bmatrix}
 t_{x} \\
    t_{y} \\
    t_{z} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\bf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
 p_{1, 1, x} & p_{1, 1, y} & p_{1, 1, z}\\
    p_{1, 2, x} & p_{1, 2, y} & p_{1, 2, z}\\
    p_{2, 1, x} & p_{2, 1, y} & p_{2, 1, z}\\
    p_{2, 2, x} & p_{2, 2, y} & p_{2, 2, z}\\
    p_{3, 1, x} & p_{3, 1, y} & p_{3, 1, z}\\
    p_{3, 2, x} & p_{3, 2, y} & p_{3, 2, z}\\
\end{bmatrix} ^T$

$\bar{\omega} = \begin{bmatrix}
 (1 - \beta)(1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2) \\
    (\beta)(1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2)\\
    (1 - \beta)(\alpha_1) \\
    (\beta)(\alpha_1)\\
    (1 - \beta)(\alpha_2) \\
    (\beta)(\alpha_2)\\
\end{bmatrix} $

With the target coordinate known as well as all the boundary coordinates, this system of equations can be solved to obtain the boundary weight $\beta$.
This however cannot be done with linear algebra seeing that this is a non-linear expression.

## Finding a weight in 3D, case 2

In the first case of 3D, the boundaries were 1D with two boundary coordinates each.
In this case, the boundaries are 2D with three boundary coordinates each.

As indicated, a point on each boundary can be represented by two vectors (with the same origin) and two boundary weights, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$;

$r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, p_{i, 3}, \beta_1, \beta_2) = p_{i,1} + \beta_1 \bar{v}_{i, 12} + \beta_2 \bar{v}_{i, 13} = p_{i,1}+ \beta_1(p_{i,2} - p_{i,1}) + \beta_2(p_{i,3} - p_{i,1}) \quad :\beta_i \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

This was expanded and factorised so that each of the coordinates could be expressed individually together with a weight;

$r_i(p_{i, 1}, p_{i, 2}, p_{i, 3}, \beta_1, \beta_2) = p_{i,1}(1 - \beta_1 - \beta_2) + p_{i,2}(\beta_1) + p_{i,3}(\beta_2) \quad :\beta_i \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$

Because there are only two boundaries in this case, the tie-simplex between the two boundaries can be expressed by a vector and single tie-simplex weight, $\alpha$, as in the 2D case (shown in expanded and factorised format);

$t(r_{1}, r_{2}, \alpha) = r_{1}(1 - \alpha) + r_{2}(\alpha) \quad :\alpha \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]$.

After substituting the expressions for $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$, the target coordinate $t$, can be expressed in terms of the known boundary coordinates, the boundary weights $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, and tie-simplex weight $\alpha$;

\begin{align}
t &= r_{1}(1 - \alpha) + r_{2}(\alpha) \\ 
&= [p_{1,1}(1 - \beta_1 - \beta_2) + p_{1,2}(\beta_1) + p_{1,3}(\beta_2)](1 - \alpha) + [p_{2,1}(1 - \beta_1 - \beta_2) + p_{2,2}(\beta_1) + p_{2,3}(\beta_2)](\alpha) \\
&\alpha, \beta_1, \beta_2 \in \mathbb{R} [0, 1]
\end{align}

After some expanding and factorising, this can be written in matrix and vector notation as;

$\bar{t} = \bf{P}\bar{\omega}$

where

$\bar{t} = \begin{bmatrix}
 t_{x} \\
    t_{y} \\
    t_{z} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\bf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
 p_{1, 1, x} & p_{1, 1, y} & p_{1, 1, z}\\
    p_{1, 2, x} & p_{1, 2, y} & p_{1, 2, z}\\
    p_{1, 3, x} & p_{1, 3, y} & p_{1, 3, z}\\
    p_{2, 1, x} & p_{2, 1, y} & p_{2, 1, z}\\
    p_{2, 2, x} & p_{2, 2, y} & p_{2, 2, z}\\
    p_{2, 3, x} & p_{2, 3, y} & p_{2, 3, z}\\
\end{bmatrix} ^T$

$\bar{\omega} = \begin{bmatrix}
 (1 - \beta_1 - \beta_2)(1 - \alpha) \\
    (\beta_1)(1 - \alpha)\\
    (\beta_2)(1 - \alpha)\\
    (1 - \beta_1 - \beta_2)(\alpha) \\
    (\beta_1)(\alpha)\\
    (\beta_2)(\alpha)\\
\end{bmatrix} $

With the target coordinate known as well as all the boundary coordinates, this system of equations can be solved to obtain the boundary weight $\beta$.
This however cannot be done with linear algebra seeing that this is a non-linear expression.

## Finding weights in generic case

The boundaries and the tie-simplex should **always be simplices**.
The tie-simplex can be of a different order as the boundaries, but all the boundaries should be of the same order.

Given the generic case where $B$ number of boundaries are found and is expressed by $C$ number of boundary coordinates each, in $N$ dimensions.
When $C$ number of boundary coordinates are present, the number of boundary weights $\beta$ is equal to $C - 1$.
If $B$ number of boundaries are present, the number of tie-simplex weights $\alpha$ is equal to $B - 1$.

$\bar{t} = \begin{bmatrix}
 t_{x} \\
    t_{y} \\
    t_{z} \\
    \vdots \\
    t_{N} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\bf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
 p_{1, 1, x} & p_{1, 1, y} & p_{1, 1, z} & \dots & p_{1, 1, N}\\
    p_{1, 2, x} & p_{1, 2, y} & p_{1, 2, z} & \dots & p_{1, 2, N}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    p_{1, C, x} & p_{1, C, y} & p_{1, C, z} & \dots & p_{1, C, N}\\
 p_{2, 1, x} & p_{2, 1, y} & p_{2, 1, z} & \dots & p_{2, 1, N}\\
    p_{2, 2, x} & p_{2, 2, y} & p_{2, 2, z} & \dots & p_{2, 2, N}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    p_{2, C, x} & p_{2, C, y} & p_{2, C, z} & \dots & p_{2, C, N}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    p_{B, C, x} & p_{B, C, y} & p_{B, C, z} & \dots & p_{B, C, N}\\
\end{bmatrix} ^T$

$\bar{\omega} = \begin{bmatrix}
 (1 - \Sigma \beta)(1 - \Sigma \alpha) \\
    (\beta_1)(1 - \Sigma \alpha)\\
    (\beta_2)(1 - \Sigma \alpha)\\
    \vdots \\
    (\beta_{C-1})(1 - \Sigma \alpha)\\
 (1 - \Sigma \beta)(\alpha_1) \\
    (\beta_1)(\alpha_1)\\
    (\beta_2)(\alpha_1)\\
    \vdots \\
    (\beta_{C-1})(\alpha_1)\\
 (1 - \Sigma \beta)(\alpha_2) \\
    (\beta_1)(\alpha_2)\\
    (\beta_2)(\alpha_2)\\
    \vdots \\
    (\beta_{C-1})(\alpha_2)\\
    \vdots \\
 (1 - \Sigma \beta)(\alpha_{B-1}) \\
    (\beta_1)(\alpha_{B-1})\\
    (\beta_2)(\alpha_{B-1})\\
    \vdots \\
    (\beta_{C-1})(\alpha_{B-1})\\
\end{bmatrix} $

$\Sigma \alpha = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{B-1} \alpha_i \quad : \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}[0, 1] $

$\Sigma \beta = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{C-1} \beta_j \quad : \beta_j \in \mathbb{R}[0, 1] $

With the target coordinate known as well as all the boundary coordinates, this system of equations can be solved to obtain the boundary weights $\beta$.
This however cannot be done with linear algebra seeing that this is a non-linear expression.

If any $\alpha_i$ < 0, $\alpha_i$ > 1 or $\beta_j$ < 0, $\beta_j$ > 1 the target coordinate is outside the boundaries and tie-simplices connecting the sets of boundary coordinates.